# Can I upload hundreds of music files inside firebase storage?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, backend, storage

I'm building a web music player with ReactJS and I want to store hundreds of songs in a database and play it on the website.

Can I put all these songs in the firebase storage? (All the content that I've seen of firebase storage was related to images, thats why I'm not sure if I can do the same with audio).

At first I was thinking of playing youtube music from livestreams but I want to monetize the website so it won't be possible to do it that way.
I searched a lot for this but I only found android solutions and I didn't understand it properly.

(Also, I'm kinda new to stack overflow and I dont know if I should be asking questions without code in this website like this, let me know if I can).

Comment: Cloud Storage is the storage solution for many of your favorite services, such as Snapchat. Hundreds of files is not something it'll blink at.

Whether you can implement your use-case on Cloud Storage therefor depends almost exclusively on your own skill level at translating the use-case into the necessary API calls.

Comment: While developers on Stack Overflow can help with individual steps in that process, it's much more likely they can do so if you break down the problem into smaller steps, try to implement each individual step on your own, and then report back with a smaller/more concrete problem if/when you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Storage is the storage solution for many of your favorite services, such as Snapchat. Hundreds of files is not something it'll blink at.

Whether you can implement your use-case on Cloud Storage therefor depends almost exclusively on your own skill level at translating the use-case into the necessary API calls.

While developers on Stack Overflow can help with individual steps in that process, it's much more likely they can do so if you break down the problem into smaller steps, try to implement each individual step on your own, and then report back with a smaller/more concrete problem if/when you get stuck.